# Error while running digits-devserver

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, nvidia-digits

When I run `./digits-devserver` on Ubuntu 12.04 I get following error:

```
./digits-devserver
  ___ ___ ___ ___ _____ ___
 |   \_ _/ __|_ _|_   _/ __|
 | |) | | (_ || |  | | \__ \
 |___/___\___|___| |_| |___/ 5.1-dev

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/myuser/Desktop/DIGITS/digits/__main__.py", line 70, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/myuser/Desktop/DIGITS/digits/__main__.py", line 55, in main
    import digits.webapp
  File "digits/webapp.py", line 47, in <module>
    import digits.views  # noqa
  File "digits/views.py", line 18, in <module>
    from digits import dataset, extensions, model, utils, pretrained_model
  File "digits/extensions/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .data import *  # noqa
  File "digits/extensions/data/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import imageProcessing
  File "digits/extensions/data/imageProcessing/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .data import DataIngestion
  File "digits/extensions/data/imageProcessing/data.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .forms import DatasetForm
  File "digits/extensions/data/imageProcessing/forms.py", line 6, in <module>
    from flask.ext.wtf import Form
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/exthook.py", line 62, in load_module
    __import__(realname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flaskext/wtf/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    __all__ += fields.__all__
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__all__'
Exception KeyError: KeyError(28050128,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
```

What can be the source of this error and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

DIGITS only officially supports Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04:

https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/blob/digits-5.0/docs/BuildDigits.md#building-digits

So the first thing I'd try would be upgrading your system. Other than that, go through the list of requirements and make sure you've installed the correct versions of everything:

https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/blob/digits-5.0/requirements.txt